# How to convert for loop to list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
a = []
b = {}
for list1 in tasks:
    for dict2 in list1:
        b.update(dict2)
    a.append(b)
```

How can I write this code as list comprehension?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
a = [ [ b.update(dict2) for dict2 in list1 ] for list1 in tasks ]
```

my json:

```
tasks = [[{'tuition_eea_amount': '2083', 'tuition_eea_currency': 'EUR', 'tuition_eea_unit': 'year'}, 
{'tuition_international_amount': '16200', 'tuition_international_currency': 'EUR', 'tuition_international_unit': 'year'}], 
[{'tuition_eea_amount': '2083', 'tuition_eea_currency': 'EUR', 'tuition_eea_unit': 'year'}, 
{'tuition_international_amount': '16200', 'tuition_international_currency': 'EUR', 'tuition_international_unit': 'year'}]]
```

I want to convert it into:

```
a = [[{'tuition_eea_amount': '2083', 'tuition_eea_currency': 'EUR', 'tuition_eea_unit': 'year', 'tuition_international_amount': '16200', 'tuition_international_currency': 'EUR', 'tuition_international_unit': 'year'}, 
{'tuition_eea_amount': '2083', 'tuition_eea_currency': 'EUR', 'tuition_eea_unit': 'year', 'tuition_international_amount': '16200', 'tuition_international_currency': 'EUR', 'tuition_international_unit': 'year'}]]
```

There should be one list, with two dictionaries inside. But now it is two lists with two dictionaries inside each of them.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? Your first snippet seems to be making `a = [b, b, ... b]`

Comment: @quamrana my first snippet is working and returns me the list I want.

Comment: It does because both of your lists in `tasks` have the same dicts. Try with different data and you will see that the final result is still the same

Comment: @Tomerikoo, thanks for clarification. I didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to create a merged dict from all dicts in each list in `tasks`. For thing you can do:

```
a = [{k: v for dict2 in list1 for k, v in dict2.items()} for list1 in tasks]
```

In case of repeating keys between the dicts, this will save the last one encountered.

---

The dict-comp used here is basically the equivalent of using `update` in a loop. It iterates over all dicts, and for each *updates* the new dict with all the `key: value` pairs. Then te list-comp just does that for all sub-lists in `tasks`.

Comment: Nice! It gets the job done! I didn't know we can write multiple for loops inside one list or dict.